# My Computer hangs at BIOS logo

Tags: boot, bios

I have a desktop with AMD triple core CPU. At start-up, it hangs at BIOS logo, and sometimes the screen goes black.

I can't enter the BIOS settings, because the keyboard doesn't response more than one time (e.g <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

I disconnected all parts (RAM, HDD, Graphics Card), replaced the PSU and Graphics Card, applied new thermal paste to the CPU cooling. I'm not getting any sound alarms.

Comment: Perhaps the motherboard lacks support for the CPU and need to be updated (firmware). You can probably research this on the manufacturer's website. Also I think you need to have the RAM and CPU plugged in, or else you won't be able to do anything. @TFM Everyone loves commas, language teachers most of all.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин: I was referring to the original post, before my edit: http://superuser.com/posts/507224/revisions. My comment is a bit off now, after the corrections.

Comment: @TFM, I was trying to have a little fun on Adler's expense.

Comment: The motherboard and cpu were working perfectly

Comment: @Adler: If you are having problems with other people's edits on your question, that flag the post to a moderator. Your original post and your edits lack good formatting and punctuation, and difficult to follow. Please see http://superuser.com/faq#editing.

Comment: Have you changed anything recently? Added new hardware, replaced something? Check the connections to that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could do.

1. Contact your mainboard manufacturer for technical support.
2. See if the mainboard manual has a jumper that you could use that would force the BIOS to reset.
3. Try a different keyboard to see if the keyboard is the problem.
4. Disconnect the mouse, perhaps that is interfering.
5. Take out all of the RAM and startup like that and see if it works.

Comment: I vote on the resetting BIOS settings one. 1 is also possible but harder to test. 5 should not lock the start-up.